# Can't click on other form when new forms appears C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm making an ATM simulator and I am currently trying to have a button on one form to create another form (the ATM). I've been able to do this but only for one form as when the new form appears I am unable to click on the other form which has the "add atm" button.  I've tried `Form.Show`, `Form.ShowDialog` and `Applications.Run()` using C#.

here is the code:

```
public class Program
    {
        private Account[] ac = new Account[3];
        private ATM atm;
        public Form1 form1;

         /* This function initilises the 3 accounts 
         * and instanciates the ATM class passing a referance to the account information

         */
        public Program()
        {

            ac[0] = new Account(300, 1111, 111111);
            ac[1] = new Account(750, 2222, 222222);
            ac[2] = new Account(3000, 3333, 333333);

            Thread form1thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startform)); //Creates ATM Form
            //Thread atm2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(start));

            form1thread.Start();
            //atm2.Start();
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program();
        }

        public void startform()
        {
            form1 = new Form1(this);
            form1.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void newatm()
        {
            atm = new ATM(ac);
            atm.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void makethread()
        {
            Thread newatm = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startform));
            newatm.Start();
        }
    }
```

and in form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Program program;

    public Form1(Program program)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.program = program;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowDialog();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        program.newatm();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because you are doing a ShowModal somewhere in code.. can you show the code that you are using so that we can limit all the guess work..?

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Answer (score 3):

Use the form's `Show` method instead of the `ShowDialog` method if you don't want the form to be a modal dialog.

You'll also need to ensure that you create and show the form from the UI thread, not a background thread.  Based on your code, you have no need for creating a background thread at all, just create/show the form directly from the constructor.

Comment: If i use Show then i get an error telling me to use ShowDialog because i am using threads

Comment: @SnazzyWolf Then don't create/show the form from a background thread.  Create and show the form from the UI thread.  All Controls should be created/accessed from the UI thread.  If you need to do other work in a background thread first then marshal back to the UI thread using a `BackgroundWorker` or `Control.BeginInvoke` to show the new form.  Based on the code in your edit, there's no need to do any of that, just don't start a new thread in the first place.

Comment: I need to use threads, that's part of the task

Comment: @SnazzyWolf If you're being tasked with using threads then you should be using them *appropriately*.  This is not an appropriate use of the `Thread` class.  You should create a new thread to perform long running *non-UI* work.  If you need an example of doing work in a thread, come up with a non-UI related task to perform.